# Fourier Transforms of Convolutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, fourier-transform

Straightforward computations lead to the following standard property of Fourier transformation: it transforms convolutions into products, *i.e.* for functions $f$ and $g$ Schwartz class we have
$$\widehat{f \star g} = \hat{f} \hat{g} \qquad (1) $$

I am interested in the corresponding property in the more general setting of Fourier transforms on some dual groups. Let $G$ be a reductive group, $\pi$ and automorphic representation of $G$, and define the Fourier transform of functions in the Hecke algebra by
$$\widehat{f}(\pi) = \mathrm{tr} \ \pi(f)$$

Property $(1)$ does not always hold in this more general setting. It is easy to check that $\pi(a \star b) = \pi(a) \circ \pi(b)$, hence the property (1) remains true in cases of multiplicty one.

Let $K$ be a (say maximal) compact subgroup and $f$ a function in the Hecke algebra. By definition, $\pi(f) \circ \pi(\mathbf{1}_K)$ is 0 when $\pi$ is ramified, by multiplicity one indeed $\widehat{\mathbf{1}_K}(\pi)=\mathbf{1}_{K-\text{unram}}(\pi)$. In that case, I would like to state property (1), however there is no reason because
$$\mathrm{tr}(\pi(f) \circ \pi(\mathbf{1}_K)) = \mathbf{1}_{K-\text{unram}}(\pi) \  \mathrm{tr} \ \pi(f_{|\text{K-unram}}) $$

and this last trace if a priori not $\mathrm{tr} \ \pi(f)$, right? Anyway, my question without those details is:

> Given a function $f$, is there a $g$ such that $$\widehat{g \star \mathbf{1}_K} = \hat{f} \cdot \widehat{\mathbf{1}_K}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  Wouldn't (1) in your setting mean tr $\pi(f) \pi(g) = $ tr $\pi(f)$ tr $\pi(g)$?  But trace is not multiplicative.

Comment: @Kimball Yes that is my problem: is there any analogous property to (1) if it is not true, giving a method to "twist" test functions?

Comment: @Kimball I stated the problem in my more precise situation where I hope a way to "twist a Fourier transform". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't even understand why you are calling tr $\pi(f)$ a Fourier transform.  A priori, it's just a map from functions on $G$ to functions on the unitary (say) dual of $G$.  It's not invertible for instance.  Normally one looks at Fourier transforms on Lie algebras.

Comment: @Kimball Isn't it the language used in the Paley-Wiener theorem of Clozel-Delorme for instance?

Comment: I haven't read the Clozel-Delorme papers but don't they only talk about Fourier transforms on Lie algebras of tori?  Fourier theory doesn't really work on non-abelian groups---that's why you have things like the Selberg transform appearing in trace formulas.

Comment: @Kimball I think the OP is calling $tr(\pi(f))$ to be Fourier transform of $f$ as an analogue of one dimensional representation (as if $tr\pi$ is a character). Also I am not sure what you meant by "not invertible". One can get back $f$ by a Plancherel integral: $$f(1)=\int_{\hat{G}}tr(\pi(f))d\mu(\pi).$$

Comment: @SubhajitJana I believe that  knowing tr($\pi(f)$) for various $\pi$'s only determines the orbital integrals of $f$, no?  (This does not contradict recovering $f(1)$, as the orbit of $1$ is singleton.)

Comment: @Kimball I meant that you can recover $f(g)$ for all $g\in G$ by suitably translating $f$ inside the Plancherel integrand by a regular representation.